# I have old magnesium 1931 newspaper photo plates..how to clean?

Tags: print-preservation

I want to get off the old ink and all the white specks and still keep the plates safe.

Answer (score 1):

Use fine brass bristle brush to remove the corrosion (careful it might do more harm than good) followed by pencil eraser. You might try the eraser first. start with artgum from an office supply store. If too soft, use pink pearl pencil eraser. These erasers will polish and remove some of the corrosion.